# AngularJS, Tabbed Forms and Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm building a view like the one below but have some doubts on how to do it. I don't want to make unneccessary calls to the service but I want to keep things simple.
[image: customers view]

**My thoughts**
The small piece of basic information with name etc will always be visible. I guess this little piece would be a nice directive? (never wrote one myself)

For the tabs I'm not sure how to do it at all? Will I make every tab a view with it's own controller (and a service that will fetch specific data for that view) or should I fetch a huge customerobject and put in some storage or..?

Would appreciate your thoughts and answers about best practice, regards!

Comment: Have you tried google?

Comment: Oh I have. I also read two books about AngularJs. Was that your answer?

Comment: http://www.reactiongifs.us/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/dont_believe_you_anchorman.gif

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use angular-ui-bootstrap directives, it includes some useful directives.
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will look into it. Don't want to invent another wheel

Comment: Of course, you can only use bootstrap css and js to implement it.